# registry script - can you assign a decimal value without the dword keyword

Tags: registry

Which of the following registry scripts is syntactically correct?  Will both work?  Is one preferred?

**Sample A:**

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\explorer]
"nodrivetypeautorun"=255
```

**Sample B:**

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\policies\explorer]
"nodrivetypeautorun"=dword:000000FF
```

Technically, in this example, the "nodrivetypeautorun" element is a dword data type.  I don't want to fixate on the "nodrivetypeautorun" element.  I am only concerned about dword data types and the proper way to set them in a registry script.

I think that Sample A will fail to import the value, and I think I can prove it.  What I need is a reference online that will back me up because some people that I work with won't take my word for it, even if I demonstrate the problem.  I've spent some time with google and can't find what I'm looking for.  The preferred answer to this question should have such a reference, but I'd settle for a general consensus from other professionals.

Comment: i resolved this by simple demonstration, using regedit to observe the results after each step:

test1.reg will attempt to add two keys to the registry, one will fail:

REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test]
"test1"=dword:000000FF
"test2"=255

test2.reg, will attempt to change the test1 value from 255 to 300, and fail.

REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test]
"test1"=300

undo.reg will remove the test entries from the registry.

REGEDIT4

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Test]

This clearly demonstrates that you cannot add or modify dword values without the dword keyword.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MS Knowledgebase has an article on this.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516/

Here's the excerpt you'd be interested in:

> Syntax of .Reg Files A .reg file has
>   the following syntax:
>
> RegistryEditorVersion Blank line
>   [RegistryPath1] 
>   "DataItemName1"="DataType1:DataValue1"
>   DataItemName2"="DataType2:DataValue2"
>   Blank line [RegistryPath2] 
>   "DataItemName3"="DataType3:DataValue3"

So it would seem the 'official' way to set a value includes specifying the 'DataType', in your case 'dword'.